# Apache send HTML without comments

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, gzip, hash

I have a problem with my Apache Webserver, I got 2 environments: Development and Production. Both have the same configuration, but the first one sends the HTMLs exactly as they've been created, the second one doesn't send exactly the same file. They omit whitespaces, comments, and other chars that for a browser doesn't care, but if my app generate hash from this files and the apache changes the file, the hash won't be the same.

I've been looking for the differences but I nothing appears. Any suggestion?

My apache2 config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName XXX
ServerAlias XXX XX.XX.XX.XX
DocumentRoot /var/www/
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/api-error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel info

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/api-access.log "%h %t %T %D %m %X %U"

        # Timestamp | bytes Downloaded | bytes Uploaded | PlayerID | IP | URL
        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/traffic-access.log "%{%s}t|%O|%I|%{Referer}i|%a|%U"
        ServerSignature On
        Alias /img/screenshots  /dev/shm/screenshots
        #Alias /videos /mnt/STORAGE/videos
        Alias /awstats-icon/ /usr/share/awstats/icon/
        ScriptAlias /aw-api-stats/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/

        <Location /server-status>
           SetHandler server-status
           Allow from all 
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
ExtendedStatus On
```

This is my production config file and the modules enabled are the following with default values:

alias.conf          authz_groupfile.load  cgi.load      env.load          php5.conf        setenvif.conf
alias.load          authz_host.load       deflate.conf  mime.conf         php5.load        setenvif.load
auth_basic.load     authz_user.load       deflate.load  mime.load         reqtimeout.conf  status.conf
authn_file.load     autoindex.conf        dir.conf      negotiation.conf  reqtimeout.load  status.load
authz_default.load  autoindex.load        dir.load      negotiation.load  rewrite.load

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

can't be specific without knowing your configuration, but your production environment is set up to use a HTML minifier. You'll need to dig through your configuration to put exceptions to the pages that you don't want Apache to minify. Check what installed modules you have on your web server.